# Making threaded private messaging system

Tags: sql

I'm working on making a thread-like private messaging feature on my site. Im kind of a novice but this is how i've set it up

Two tables:

```
conversations
id, subject, user_one (userid), user_two (userid)
1, test, 13, 14
2, test again, 13, 14

conversation_messages
id, cid, body, date, sender (userid)
1, 1, hello, unixtime, 13
2, 1, hello yourself, unixtime, 14
3, 2, cheese, unixtime, 13
```

This is to display a users Inbox where USERID is id of current logged in user.

```
SELECT c.*, max(cr.date) as date, u.username, cr.sender FROM conversations c
JOIN conversation_replies cr ON cr.cid = c.id
JOIN users u ON u.id = cr.sender
WHERE (c.user_one = '.USERID.' OR c.user_two = '.USERID.')

foreach($inbox as $message) {......................
```

For some reason even if a user has more than 1 conversations going on between different users, it will only return one row with the above SQL.

Am i thinking wrong here??

Why?

Comment: Doesn't `max` force the result set to be just one row?

Comment: can you create [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) demo with some sample data and your expected output. You can hardcode a userid for example. It would be easier for others to try something out.